# Trying to use wildcard in IF statement

Tags: windows, batch

I'm trying to execute some commands based on the machine hostname but am having 
trouble getting it to work.  I want the command to run only if the hostname starts with "Machine".  Do IF statements support wildcards?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq skip=1" %%i in (`wmic computersystem get name`) do (
  set name=%%i
  goto :done
  )
:done
if [%name%]==[MachineXXXX] start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "download url"
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use wild-cards in the sense you want, but you can achieve the result you require by using a [variable substring](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html):

```
if [%name:0,7%]==[Machine] start ...
```

An alternative approach would be to use the matching functions in [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html):

```
echo %name% | findstr /b /c:"Machine" && start ...
```

This uses an external program, so is less efficient in this case, but it may be a useful technique for more complex matches (eg using `findstr /r`).